# NSArray add objects from other array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have three `NSArray` objects. I need to add all objects for this array to `NSArray` that is called **allMyObjects**.

Have `NSArray` standard solution to make it for example via initialization method or do I need make custom method to retrieve all objects from other arrays and put all retrieved objects to my **allMyObjects** array?

Comment: NSMutableArray has an -addObjectsFromArray: method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

once see this one ,

```
NSArray *newArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"hi",@"how",@"are",@"you",nil];
    NSArray *newArray1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"hello",nil];
    NSArray *newArray2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:newArray,newArray1,nil];
    NSString *str=[newArray2 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()\n "];
    str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
     NSArray *resultArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

O/P:-

```
(
    hi,
    how,
    are,
    you,
    hello
)
```

Comment: Probably a better way to do it than I suggested, while keeping the order correct. +1

Answer (score 26):

Don't know if this counts as a sufficiently simple solution to your problem, but this is the straight forward way to do it (as alluded to by other answerers, too):

```
NSMutableArray *allMyObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: array1]; 
[allMyObjects addObjectsFromArray: array2]; 
[allMyObjects addObjectsFromArray: array3];
```

Comment: This is the method I tried to find. ty. But does it initialize array?

Comment: @GxocT not sure exactly what you are asking, but the `arrayWithArray:` method is a convenience constructor that allocates and initializes the array in one call.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `addObjectsFromArray:` method on your `allMyObjects` array.

Comment: ...provided that it's mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Here am adding code for store and get datas from array to array.

To store array to array

```
NSMutableArray rowOneRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"45",@"29",@"12",nil];
 NSMutableArray   rowTwoRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"41",@"45",@"45",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowThreeRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"12",@"45",@"22",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowFourRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"45",@"12",@"61",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowFiveRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"12",@"14",@"14",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowSixRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"12",@"12",@"12",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowSevenRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"12",@"36",@"83",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowEightRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"37",@"57",@"45",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowNineRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"12",@"93",@"83",nil];
   NSMutableArray rowTenRoundData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"16",@"16",@"16",nil];
   NSArray circleArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:rowOneRoundData,rowTwoRoundData,rowThreeRoundData,rowFourRoundData,rowFiveRoundData,rowSixRoundData,rowSevenRoundData,rowEightRoundData,rowNineRoundData,rowTenRoundData, nil];
```

Get data from Circle Array

```
for (int i= 0; i<10;i++)
{
NSArray *retriveArrar = [[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
}
```